# how to pass uncertain parameter to method flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a method like following:

```
  void reverseWeekdayStatus({alarmClock,sundayIsSelected}){
    alarmClock.sundayIsSelected = !alarmClock.sundayIsSelected ?? false;
    update();
  }
```

alarmClock is a model:

```
class AlarmClock {
  bool sundayIsSelected;
  bool mondayIsSelected;
  bool tuesdaySelected;
  bool wednesdayIsSelected;
  bool thursdayIsSelected;
  bool fridayIsSelected;
  bool saturdayIsSelected;

  AlarmClock({
    this.sundayIsSelected = false,
    this.mondayIsSelected = false,
    this.tuesdaySelected = false,
    this.wednesdayIsSelected = false,
    this.thursdayIsSelected = false,
    this.fridayIsSelected = false,
    this.saturdayIsSelected = false,
  });
}
```

so for this method I want to not just `sundayIsSelected` also the rest like `mondayIsSelected` could be reversed if I implement this method, what I did is following:

```
  void reverseWeekdayStatus({alarmClock,whichDay}){
    alarmClock.whichDay = !alarmClock.whichDay ?? false;
    update();
  }
```

And pass `mondayIsSelected` for example to `whichDay`, and then I got an error since `whichDay` does not exist in `alarmClock`, another way I thought is to create separate methods like from monday to sunday, is there a smarter way to do this job? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
class AlarmClock {
  bool sundayIsSelected;

  AlarmClock({
    this.sundayIsSelected = false,
  });
}
```

On current mode, you are providing default for each field. If you don't pass any value for `sundayIsSelected` it will get default value `false`. But `sundayIsSelected` is not nullable. It can't be null.

Therefore, `alarmClock.sundayIsSelected ?? false` will never get false.

To reverse, you just like to change the value then do

```dart
 void reverseWeekdayStatus({
    alarmClock,
  }) {
    alarmClock.sundayIsSelected = !alarmClock.sundayIsSelected;
   ...
  }
```

It will switch the bool when ever gets call. You can do conditional state on update case, and it is an optional parameter with default value.

```dart
void reverseWeekdayStatus({alarmClock, bool switchSundayState = false}) {
  if (switchSundayState) {
    alarmClock.sundayIsSelected = !alarmClock.sundayIsSelected;
  }
}
```

Another technic is using `copyWith` constructor, it is nullable (optional) named constructor, use current value if we don't pass value for field.

```dart
class AlarmClock {
  final bool sundayIsSelected;

  AlarmClock({
    this.sundayIsSelected = false,
  });

  AlarmClock copyWith({
    bool? sundayIsSelected,
  }) {
    return AlarmClock(
      sundayIsSelected: sundayIsSelected ?? this.sundayIsSelected,
    );
  }
}
```

And use cases

`alarmClock = alarmClock.copyWith(sundayIsSelected: true);`

Comment: hi Yeasin, i did as you explained, it indeed works, thanks a lot:)